# In a .NET application, how do you model this SQL relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

**BACKGROUND TO THE DOMAIN**

I have a .NET application with a SQL Server database underneath. Each customer has their own database.

In that database, I have a table called `Label` which is empty on new installations, and gets populated when the user creates their own labels.

**NEW REQUIREMENT**

There is a new requirement that when the database is patched for the next release, we should add some default labels that come with the system.

These default labels must have the same ID in every customer database that they are added to (via SQL patching on upgrade), i.e. it must be 'static data'

**ATTEMPT 1**

I tried giving these 'default labels' an enormous ID number, e.g. above 200,000, since we 'know' to a decent degree of certainty that all customers will have no more than 5 - 10 rows in this table, so since the `ID` column is of type `identity (1, 1)`, no customers will have already used this ID in this table.

But I've been told we want to avoid this because it seems like bad practice to mix static and dynamic data in one table.

**ATTEMPT 2**

I tried adding a new identical table called `StaticLabel`, also with an `ID` column of type `int identity(1, 1)`.

I added a corresponding entity in the application (`StaticLabelEntity.cs`), an entity map (`StaticLabelEntity.cs`, using fluent NHibernate) and a repository (`StaticLabelRepository.cs`).

Now, in the existing `LabelService.cs` code that retrieves labels from the database (via the repository), I tell it to get both the `Labels` and `StaticLabels`, and combine them into one list of `ILabel`.

This works fine when viewing the labels config in my application

When it comes to assigning labels to an author (an author can have many labels), there's already an `AuthorLabel` table with a foreign key to the `Author` table (`AuthorId`) and one to the `Label` table (`LabelId`).

I guess we need to add another column to `AuthorLabel`, which is a foreign key to `StaticLabel`, and also add a check constraint so that only `LabelId` OR `StaticLabelId` is populated.

**QUESTION**

Does what I've done in Attempt #2 sound like a good idea? It seems a bit weird and like there might be some better way that I haven't heard of due to lack of experience

It starts to get weird in the code if I do this, because I end up with two properties on the `AuthorLabel` entity (a `Label` and a `StaticLabel`) where one is always null.

This will then propagate through the code and I'll end up with lots of 'if staticlabel property is not null, then x, else y' etc - it feels a bit messy.

Comment: *I tried giving these 'default labels' an enormous ID number, e.g. above 200,000*, `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Labels ON`, `INSERT Labels(ID,Text) VALUES(-1,'Static 1'),(-2,'Static 2')`... ;)

Comment: *I guess we need to add another column to AuthorLabel, which is a foreign key to StaticLabel, and also add a check constraint so that only LabelId OR StaticLabelId is populated.* - sounds horrific. *- it feels a bit messy.* - it was my first thought too, for the same reason

Comment: Third option: add another column to Label, "LabelType" default "CustomerDefined". Add your 10 static ones, regardless the ID, with some relevant LabelType like "CoverPage", "Footer", "Whatever".. then your code can look them up by this column, not the ID. Even offer the column up to the customer so they can group their labels (but don't let the customer use your reserved words)

Comment: @CaiusJard Really appreciate your ideas - thank you. I really like your 3rd option, but unfortunately we need to make sure the ID is static across all customer sites

This is because our localisation tool has a database which stores chinese translations of all strings in our database. It stores the translations with a reference to the schema name, table name, and the ID of the record in that table being translated, then translations are applied via patching using the ID

In that case, it kind of seems like your 'insert negative IDs for the static rows' idea may be our best shot?...

Comment: It might well be indeed.. Hopefully there won't be any snags with the use of negative numbers, like the tool that does the matching having some Regex that insists the ID be just `\d+` ... check on whether a negative will cause a problem. If it does, then you could consider something else, which will probably be removing the relationships to label, renaming the table, making a new label table (hah) with the static values, then appending the old values + 10 (or whatever) then reseeding the identity on the new table and recreating the relationships. Awful.. and only gives you space for 10 static

Comment: labels. It might be a lot of work but going back to the "add column" idea and having it universally be a "TranslationKey" column in *every* table i.e. divorcing translations from the ID, then you can always add new static values with any id because it's not using them any more... Or changing the tooling so it *can* cope with negatives, and having all your static/translateds always be negative in every table....

Comment: @CaiusJard Adding a TranslationKey column is actually a great idea and should work for what I need - in the translation tool we could then change this table (Label)'s mapping so that its records are identified by the  TranslationKey rather than the ID, and filter to only include records where TranslationKey is not null!